# Switch between two decorators Material-Calender

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar

I am using this library [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) to show customized calender view in my app.

I am using a custom decorator to change the text color of the dates in like image below.
[image]

But when i select any date in i want the date text color to change to white and when again to red or blue when i select another date.

[image]

Like in above pic you can see that backgroud color is changeing but text color remains same as before.
But I want the date text color to change to white and when I select another date previous date should again chagne to its respective date like it was before selection.